# Can Python ctypes load a 32bit C library on x86-64?

Tags: python, 32bit-64bit, ctypes

I have a 64 bit RHEL host with 32 bit libraries installed. One vendor has a 32 bit .so I'd like to load into Python using ctypes.

```
from ctypes import CDLL
CDLL('32bitdinosaur.so')                        

OSError: 32bitdinosaur.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

Of course 64 bit libraries are OK. Eg:

```
CDLL('libc.so.6')
```

Works fine.

Comment: You probably need to run a 32-bit Python interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the best way to do this is to have a 32 bit python in a separate process load the .so, and call the 32 bit python from a 64 bit Python.

Comment: How exactly do you run both 32bit and 64bit python at the same time on debian linux?