# Accessing a 32bit with python on a Debian 64bit with CDLL lib (or other)

Tags: python, ubuntu, debian, 32bit-64bit, ctypes

I'm trying for ages to access a 32bit C compiled lib within an 64bit Ubuntu. I'm using python and CDLL lib in order to make it happen but with no success so far. I can easily open the same 32bit lib on a 32bit OS, and the 64bit version on a 64bit OS.

So, what I'm asking is if anyone knows a way to encapsulate/sandbox/wrap the lib so I can achieve my goal. That way I can use a single 64bit server to access the 32 and 64bit versions of those libs.

If someone knows another python lib that can make the trick please let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Python ctypes load a 32bit C library on x86-64?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015970/can-python-ctypes-load-a-32bit-c-library-on-x86-64)

Comment: Apparently you have access to the 64-bit version(s), so why do you also need the 32-bit version(s)? If you could explain what you're ultimately trying to do and why, then someone might have a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can do this in the same process - we are talking about arithmetic here: 32bit pointers are different from 64bit pointers, so trying to reference them in the same process ... well, I am not sure what happens when trying to access a memory area which is not accessible or which is not supposed to be accessed (I guess Segmentation fault? ).

The only solution I can think of is it to have a separate Python 32 bit instance that runs in its own process. Then, with some form of IPC you can call the python32 bit instance from your 64 bit instance.

Answer (score 0):

(apart from crazy hacks)

You have to have a 32-bit process to load a 32-bit library and call its functions.

You can install 32-bit version of Python side-by-side with native, 64-bit version on Debian.

See e.g. this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/29253/how-can-i-install-a-32bit-python-on-64-bit-ubuntu

Or small hack using pyenv: https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv/issues/66

Or install binary pypy release: http://pypy.org/download.html#default-with-a-jit-compiler